# Notify nurse about the frequency of a medicine the patient must take

Tags: java, list, design-patterns, notifications, frequency

When you get a prescription from a pharmacy, there is a start date associated with the medication. Medications also have a scheduled frequency that tells you when to take the doses. There are fairly common patterns for the frequencies. You can take them every 4 hours. You can take them once a day. You can take them with meals or just before bed. You can also take them PRN or "as needed." Many medications also have a stop. You may need to take the medication for 7 days. You may need to take a certain number of doses. You may also take the medication for the rest of your life. Assume you have to implement a system to tell nurses when a patient should receive medications. How would you model a schedule for a medication that handles start dates, end dates, and frequencies?

I have done basic design ..but I'm stuck with implementing the schedule functionality (notification functionality that notifies the nurse bout medicine frequency )

The solution i have is

**Frequency Class**

```
    package patientmedicine;
```

public class Frequency {

```
public PartoftheDay part;
public enum PartoftheDay
{
    Morning,
    Afternoon,
    Evening,
    Night
}

public Frequency( PartoftheDay part ) {
    this.part = part;

} 

public PartoftheDay getPart() {
    return part;
}
public void setPart(PartoftheDay part) {
    this.part = part;
}
```

}

**Medicine Class**

```
    package patientmedicine;
```

import java.util.List;

public class Medicine {

```
private String name;
private String disease;
private String composition;
private String details;
private List<Frequency> frequencyList;



public List<Frequency> getFrequencyList() {
    return frequencyList;
}

public void setFrequencyList(List<Frequency> frequencyList) {
    this.frequencyList = frequencyList;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public Medicine(String name, String composition, String details) {
    this.name = name;
    this.setComposition(composition);
    this.setDetails(details);

}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getDisease() {
    return disease;
}
public void setDisease(String disease) {
    this.disease = disease;
}

/**
 * @return the composition
 */
public String getComposition() {
    return composition;
}

/**
 * @param composition the composition to set
 */
public void setComposition(String composition) {
    this.composition = composition;
}

/**
 * @return the details
 */
public String getDetails() {
    return details;
}

/**
 * @param details the details to set
 */
public void setDetails(String details) {
    this.details = details;
}
```

}

**Patient class**

```
    package patientmedicine;
```

import java.util.List;

public class Patient {

```
private String name;
private String disease;
private List<Medicine> medicineList;



public Patient(String name, String disease) {
    this.setName(name);
    this.setDisease(disease);

}



public List<Medicine> getMedicineList() {
    return medicineList;
}



public void setMedicineList(List<Medicine> medicineList) {
    this.medicineList = medicineList;
}



/**
 * @return the name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * @param name the name to set
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 * @return the disease
 */
public String getDisease() {
    return disease;
}

/**
 * @param disease the disease to set
 */
public void setDisease(String disease) {
    this.disease = disease;
}
```

}

**Program Class**

```
    package patientmedicine;
```

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import patientmedicine.Frequency.PartoftheDay;

public class Program {
    // private List patientList;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Frequency> freque1 = new ArrayList<Frequency>();
    freque1.add(new Frequency(PartoftheDay.Morning));
    freque1.add(new Frequency(PartoftheDay.Evening));

    // List<Medicine> medicine = new ArrayList<Medicine>();
    Medicine med1 = new Medicine("Paracetemol", "38g", "For fever");
    med1.setFrequencyList(freque1);

    List<Frequency> freque2 = new ArrayList<Frequency>();
    freque2.add(new Frequency(PartoftheDay.Morning));
    freque2.add(new Frequency(PartoftheDay.Evening));

    Medicine med2 = new Medicine("Ibuprofen", "38g", "For body pains");
    med2.setFrequencyList(freque2);

    List<Medicine> medicineList = new ArrayList<Medicine>();
    medicineList.add(med1);
    medicineList.add(med2);

    Patient patient1 = new Patient("Deepthi", "For body pains");
    patient1.setMedicineList(medicineList);

    List<Patient> patientList = new ArrayList<Patient>();
    patientList.add(patient1);

    for (Patient patientt : patientList) {
        System.out.println(patientt.getDisease());
        System.out.println(patientt.getName());

        for (Medicine medi : patientt.getMedicineList()) {

            System.out.println(medi.getDetails() + medi.getComposition()
                    + medi.getName());

            for (Frequency freq : medi.getFrequencyList()) {
                System.out.println(freq.getPart());
            }

        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: My mistake sorry. Removed JS

Comment: Do you mind editing your question and provide a little more clarity as to what you are having trouble with? What are you trying to accomplish? How have you tried to accomplish this? What part are you stuck on?

Comment: I have implemented the classes that take the patient medicines and frequencies..but Im stuck with implementing the schedule functionality (notification functionality that notifies the nurse about medicine frequency that the patient has to take everyday )

Comment: So you are looking for a way to notify the nurse when a medication needs to be taken by a certain patient?

Comment: Yea that's what i am looking for

Comment: You can make an interface which contains enough methods which are called when the medicine is given to the patient. Then make a nurse class which is nothing but an implementation of the listener interface. I can work on an detailed example for you if you want it...

Comment: I am not sure if i understood completely. Yeah if can you give me a detailed example if possible, that would help me a lot

Comment: Okay i am in my college right now. I am uploading that in my public repo. I hope that works out for you...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a partial implementation using a listener as Jay suggested. You could merge this skeletal code into your partial implementation.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

interface AlarmListener {
    void notify(Frequency.PartoftheDay time, String msg);
}

class Nurse implements AlarmListener {
    private String name;
    private Set<Frequency.PartoftheDay> times = new HashSet<>();

    Nurse(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // Add times of day that this nurse will be notified
    public void addTime(Frequency.PartoftheDay time) {
        this.times.add(time);
    }

    public void notify(Frequency.PartoftheDay time, String msg) {
        if (times.contains(time)) {
            System.out.println("Nurse " + name + ", you are being notified of event:  " + msg);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
        b.append(name).append(":  scheduled for\n");
        for (Frequency.PartoftheDay time : times) {
            b.append("  ").append(time).append("\n");
        }

        return b.toString();
    }
}

class Scheduler {
    List<AlarmListener> alarmListenerList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addListener(AlarmListener alarmListener) {
        alarmListenerList.add(alarmListener);
    }

    public void rollCall() {
        System.out.println("Roll call:");
        for (AlarmListener a : alarmListenerList) {
            System.out.println(a.toString());
        }
    }

    public void notifyListeners(Frequency.PartoftheDay time) {
        for (AlarmListener a : alarmListenerList) {
            a.notify(time, time.name());
        }
    }
}

class Frequency {
    public enum PartoftheDay
    {
        Morning,
        Afternoon,
        Evening,
        Night
    }
    public PartoftheDay part;
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Nurse alice = new Nurse("Alice");
        alice.addTime(Frequency.PartoftheDay.Morning);
        alice.addTime(Frequency.PartoftheDay.Afternoon);

        Nurse bob = new Nurse("Bob");
        bob.addTime(Frequency.PartoftheDay.Afternoon);
        bob.addTime(Frequency.PartoftheDay.Evening);

        Scheduler scheduler = new Scheduler();
        scheduler.addListener(alice);
        scheduler.addListener(bob);

        // Show who is scheduled to respond to alarms and when
        scheduler.rollCall();

        // Do this if "Morning" has arrived
        System.out.println("Morning now! ----------------");
        scheduler.notifyListeners(Frequency.PartoftheDay.Morning);
        System.out.println("");

        // Do this if "Afternoon" has arrived
        System.out.println("Afternoon now! --------------");
        scheduler.notifyListeners(Frequency.PartoftheDay.Afternoon);
        System.out.println("");

        // Do this if "Evening" has arrived
        System.out.println("Evening now! --------------");
        scheduler.notifyListeners(Frequency.PartoftheDay.Evening);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Roll call:
Alice:  scheduled for
  Morning
  Afternoon

Bob:  scheduled for
  Afternoon
  Evening

Morning now! ----------------
Nurse Alice, you are being notified of event:  Morning

Afternoon now! --------------
Nurse Alice, you are being notified of event:  Afternoon
Nurse Bob, you are being notified of event:  Afternoon

Evening now! --------------
Nurse Bob, you are being notified of event:  Evening
```

Comment: I was about to write exact same implementation, but you did it already. Good job. Can I put this in my public repo?

Comment: Yes, that's fine Jay, thanks for the idea. Please credit me if you don't mind.

Comment: Sure. You can contribute to it, if you don't mind. I put my examples there. It got some nice implementations as well ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution

Comment: @Jay Which public repo are you referring to in you comment. Can i have link to it.

Comment: Hi, just wondering is this a design pattern you are using ? if so is there a name for it or is this just an implementation you have came up with? thanks

Comment: The design pattern is named Observer.